# C++ system echo return value

Tags: c++

is there any way to system() commands will return value?

```
int abcd = system("echo %random%");
std::cout << abcd << std::endl;
```

How to do, system() commands will return some value?

Comment: Does [`man system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) answer this?

Comment: Obviously ;) Use `popen`.

Comment: To clarify the comment from @KarolyHorvath, system() will return the numeric exit status of the echo command.  If you want the text that echo is printing instead, you will need to use popen().

Answer (score 1):

`system()` returns exit-code of program executed (-1 in case of error). On UNIX You can:

```
... = WEXITSTATUS(system("exit 120"));
```

This should return `120`. Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
   int x;
   x = system( "exit 120" );
   x = WEXITSTATUS(x);
   std::cout << x << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```